# Using meshlab function with python

Tags: python, meshlab, trimesh

I am new to 3D, I have a point cloud for this I want to form a mesh using python libraries. But I am able to do with using meshlab functions those are "Filters --> Pointset -- > compute normals for pointsets" and "Filters --> Remeshing,Simplifications and Reconstruction --> Surface Reconstruction ::Poission"

Is there any methods to doing above meshlab functions with using python to make it automate.

Thanks

Answer (score 4):

You can make a system call to meshlabserver, which comes with Meshlab (it's in the Meshlab install directory).

If you run meshlabserver.exe with no arguments, it will display the following man page

> Usage: meshlabserver [logargs] [args]
>
> where logargs can be:
>
> ```
> -d filename             dump on a text file a list of all the
>                         filtering functions
>
> -l filename             log of the filters is ouput on a file
> ```
>
> where args can be:
>
> ```
> -p filename             meshlab project (.mlp) to be loaded
> -w filename [-v]        output meshlab project (.mlp) to be saved.
>                         If -v flag is specified a 3D model meshfile.ext
>                         contained in the input project will be overwritten,
>                         otherwise it will be saved in the same directory of
>                         input mesh as a new file called meshfile_out.ext.
>                         All the mesh attributes will be exported in the
>                         saved files
>
> -i filename             mesh that has to be loaded
>
> -o filename [-m <opt>]  the name of the file where to write the current mesh
>                         of the MeshLab document.
>                         If -m is specified  the specified mesh attributes will
>                         be saved in the output file. the param <opt> can be a
>                         space separated list of the following attributes:
>                             vc -> vertex colors,  vf -> vertex flags,
>                             vq -> vertex quality, vn-> vertex normals,
>                             vt -> vertex texture coords,
>                             fc -> face colors,  ff -> face flags,
>                             fq -> face quality, fn-> face normals,
>                             wc -> wedge colors, wn-> wedge normals,
>                             wt -> wedge texture coords
>
> -s filename                 the script to be applied
> ```
>
> Examples:
>
> ```
> 'meshlabserver -i input.obj -o output.ply -m vc fq wn -s meshclean.mlx'
>        the script contained in file 'meshclean.mlx' will be applied to the
>        mesh contained into 'input.obj'. The vertex coordinates and the
>        per-vertex-color, the per-face-quality and the per-wedge-normal
>        attributes will be saved into the output.ply file
>
> 'meshlabserver -i input0.obj -i input1.ply -o outproj.mlp -v -s meshclean.mlx'
>        the script file meshclean.mlx will be applied to the document
>        composed by input0.obj and input1.ply meshes.
>        The mesh input1.ply will become the current mesh of the document
>        (e.g. the mesh to which the filters operating on a single model will
>        be applied). A new output project outproj.mlp file will be generated
>        (containing references to the input0.obj an input1.ply).
>        The files input0.obj and input1.ply will be overwritten.
>
> 'meshlabserver -l logfile.txt -p proj.mlp -i input.obj -w outproj.mlp -s meshclean.mlx'
>        the mesh file input.obj will be added to the meshes referred by the
>        loaded meshlab project file proj.mlp. The mesh input.obj will become
>        the current mesh of the document, the script file meshclean.mlx will
>        be applied to the meshes contained into the resulting document.
>        the project file outproj.mlp will be generated
>        A 3D model meshfile.ext contained in the input project proj.mlp will
>        be saved in a new file called meshfile_out.ext
>        (if you want to overwrite the original files use the -v flag after
>        the outproject filename) all the attributes of the meshes will be
>        saved into the output files; the log info will be saved into the
>        file logfile.txt.
> ```
>
> Notes:
>      There can be multiple meshes loaded and the order they are listed
>   matters because
>      filters that use meshes as parameters choose the mesh based on the
>   order.
>      The format of the output mesh is guessed by the used extension.
>      Script is optional and must be in the xml format saved by MeshLab.

First, load a mesh with Meshlab, run the filters you want to run, then go to `filters >> show current filter script` and save the script somewhere so you can call it with meshlabserver.

One pro-tip: If you're loading .stl files, you have to add the following as the very first filter:

```
<filter name="Merge Close Vertices">
  <Param type="RichAbsPerc" name="Threshold" description="Merging distance" value="0" tooltip="All the vertices that closer than this threshold are merged together. Use very small values, default values is 1/10000 of bounding box diagonal. " min="0" max="0"/>
</filter>
```