# Write meshlabserver scripts for apply filter for mesh

Tags: python-3.x, meshlab

I have a mesh for analyze. I want to apply the filter cleaning and repairing and after remove isolated pieces in GUI.
But i want to write script in python3.5 using meshlabserver. How do it? 
For example try use mlx script but dont know how apply this method for my task.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Using meshlab function with python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54143202/using-meshlab-function-with-python)

Answer (score 1):

You can try out my [MeshLabXML](https://github.com/3DLIRIOUS/MeshLabXML) library for scripting MeshLab with Python, it is designed for just this sort of thing.

Answer (score 0):

If you always want to apply the same script, just save a "cleanVertex.mlx" file as this:

```
<!DOCTYPE FilterScript>
<FilterScript>
 <filter name="Remove Duplicate Vertices"/>
 <filter name="Remove Unreferenced Vertices"/>
 <filter name="Re-Orient all faces coherentely"/>
</FilterScript>
```

and then run meshlabserver using the -s argument as this:

```
meshlabserver -i input.ply -o output.ply -s cleanVertex.mlx
```

If you really need to do that in python, just can use the subprocess package:

```
proc = subprocess.Popen(["meshlabserver", "-i", "input.ply", "-o", "output.ply", "-s", "cleanVertex.mlx"])
```